# Program that reads multiple lines from a file and converts to a single line string

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a C program that takes a file path as a command line argument. My program then reads that file line by line, removing the endline character and adding it to a string so at the end the string is the input file but on only one line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char *line = NULL;
  char buffer[100];
  char temp[200];


  line = fgets(buffer, 100 *sizeof(char), input);

  while(line != NULL){
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
    strcat(temp, line); 
    line = fgets(buffer, 100 *sizeof(char), input);
  }

  printf("%s\n", temp);
  fclose(input);
}
```

I input a file with data:

```
This is Line 1
line 2
line 3
and this is line 4
```

and expect the string to be 
`This is Line 1line 2line 3and this is line 4`

but instead it is
`and this is line 1`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @TomKarzes That’s the attempt of removing the newline. But the code never initializes `temp` and yet uses it like it’s a string. That doesn’t help.

Comment: You need to initialize `temp`, i.e. add `temp[0] = '\0';`.  Otherwise you're picking up whatever garbage happens to be there.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Right, I realized that after my first comment.  It's clearing the wrong character, but since `temp` is uninitialized it's not working as intended.

Comment: If the line in the file ever exceeds `98` chars, `line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';` overwrites the last actual character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You risk *Undefined Behavior* for (1) failing to validate `input` is actually a valid file stream opened for reading, and (2) failing to track the maximum number of characters stored in `temp` allowing more characters to be stored than you have room for (you would invoke undefined behavior by failing to check that the *argument count* is greater than `1`, but as used in `fopen` the *sentinel* `NULL` at the end of the *argument vector* (`argv`) simply causes `fopen` to fail -- but since you fail to check that...).

Before looking at possible fixes, let's look at some general coding points. Don't use *magic numbers* in your code, e.g. `100`, `200`,

```
/* if use need constants, #define them or use an enum */
enum { BUFSZ = 100, TMPSZ = 200 };

int main (int argc, char **argv){

    char buffer[BUFSZ] = "",    /* read buffer */
        temp[TMPSZ] = "";       /* buffer for combined lines */
```

By defining constants at the beginning of each source file, if you need to adjust them over time, you don't have to go picking through each declaration, loop variable, test clause, etc.. to make sure you have make all required changes.

*Before* using command line arguments, validate your *argument count* (`argc`):

```
    if (argc < 2 ) {   /* validate at least 1 argument given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
```

*Before* reading from any file you open:

```
    if (!input) {   /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
```

When reading with `fgets`, unless you are discarding the first line, there is no need for a separate `fgets` before entering your `while` loop to read the file,

```
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSZ, input)) {   /* read each line */
        ...
    }
```

Validate whether the last character read in `buffer` is the `'\n'` characters:

```
        size_t len = strlen (buffer);       /* get length */
        if (len && buffer[len - 1] == '\n') /* check if last is '\n' */
            buffer[--len] = 0;              /* overwrite with nul-char */
```

Now to the meat and potatoes of preventing *Undefined Behavior*. You only have `TMPSZ` characters available, and if you plan to use `temp` as a string, you must make sure you leave room for the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` as the final character. (`'\0'` is equivalent to `0` (zero)). So check the length, the number of characters you have stored so far, and write at most *one less than the number of characters remaining in* `temp`,

```
        if (TMPSZ <= nchr + len + 1) {      /* room to fit in buffer? */
            strncat (temp, buffer, TMPSZ - nchr - 1); /* only what fits */
            nchr = TMPSZ - 1;          /* nchr is max (+1 for nul-char) */
            temp[nchr] = 0;            /* affirmatively nul-terminate */
            break;                          /* bail - all full */
        }
```

If you didn't reach the end of `temp` in the test above, then `buffer` will fit in `temp`, so just copy it and update the total character count:

```
        strcat (temp, buffer);              /* copy buffer to temp */
        nchr += len;                        /* update nchr */
    }
```

That's it. Putting it altogether, you can read from the file given as the first argument (or from `stdin` by default if no argument is given) and combine all lines into a single line up to `TMPSZ - 1` characters, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* if use need constants, #define them or use an enum */
enum { BUFSZ = 100, TMPSZ = 200 };

int main (int argc, char **argv){

    char buffer[BUFSZ] = "",    /* read buffer */
        temp[TMPSZ] = "";       /* buffer for combined lines */
    size_t nchr = 0;            /* total character count */
    FILE *input = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!input) {   /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSZ, input)) {   /* read each line */
        size_t len = strlen (buffer);       /* get length */
        if (len && buffer[len - 1] == '\n') /* check if last is '\n' */
            buffer[--len] = 0;              /* overwrite with nul-char */

        if (TMPSZ <= nchr + len + 1) {      /* room to fit in buffer? */
            strncat (temp, buffer, TMPSZ - nchr - 1); /* only what fits */
            nchr = TMPSZ - 1;          /* nchr is max (+1 for nul-char) */
            temp[nchr] = 0;            /* affirmatively nul-terminate */
            break;                          /* bail - all full */
        }

        strcat (temp, buffer);              /* copy buffer to temp */
        nchr += len;                        /* update nchr */
    }
    if (input != stdin) fclose (input);     /* close file if not stdin */

    printf ("'%s'\n(%zu chars)\n", temp, nchr); /* output temp */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmblines <dat/cmblines.txt
'This is Line 1line 2line 3and this is line 4'
(44 chars)
```

**Example with TMPSZ = 20**

Let's perform a test. Let's set `TMPSZ = 20` and verify our code properly protects against writing beyond the end of `temp`,

```
$ ./bin/cmblines <dat/cmblines.txt
'This is Line 1line '
(19 chars)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand the changes you're making to improve my code, however when I run your version of it I get `and this is line 4'`. Could this be a problem with the linux machine I'm running my code on?

Comment: You problem is your data file contains DOS line endings. Either run `dos2uinix yourdatafile` or replace `if (len && buffer[len - 1] == '\n')` with `while (len && (buffer[len - 1] == '\n' || buffer[len - 1] == '\r'))`. Data files with DOS ending work fine with code compiled on windows, but if you are using DOS files on a Linux box, you will have problems unless you add explicit checks for the *carriage returns*. Check your file with `hexdump -Cv filename` and look at the `0d 0a` ends. (`\r\n`)

Comment: Converting the file to a unix file worked, thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad it helped. That is a big issue you need to keep in mind. If you are using data files from someone else, always check the line endings. While you can generically always use `while (len && (buffer[len - 1] == '\n' || buffer[len - 1] == '\r'))` to trim both *newlines* and *carriage returns*, there are a lot of other scenarios where DOS line endings can cause issues. You can always check with `hexdump -Cv file` and check if the `..` shown is `0d 0a` (carriage return, newline, see [ASCIItable](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Answer (score 0):

The following program works for me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char *line = NULL;
  char buffer[100]={0};
  char temp[200]={0};


  line = fgets(buffer, 100 *sizeof(char), input);

  while(line != NULL){
      strcat(temp, line);     
      temp[strlen(temp)-1] = '\0';
      line = fgets(buffer, 100 *sizeof(char), input);
  }

  printf("%s\n", temp);
  fclose(input);
}
```